# Two column DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question has probably been asked many times, I tried all suggestions and answers I could find on SO with no success.

What I am trying to achieve is a set of boxes (divs) layed out as follow:

[image]

The order does not really matter as long as there is no empty space between these boxes.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="MyList">
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:75px;"><span>Box 1</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:65px;"><span>Box 2</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:45px;"><span>Box 3</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:85px;"><span>Box 4</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:25px;"><span>Box 5</span></div>
</div>
```

and

```
.MyList
{
    overflow:auto;
    background:lightgray;
    width:240px;
}
.ListItem {
    color: #000;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    min-height: 2em;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[And here is the result (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hzdsz/):
So far, I could get this:

[image]

I can't:

- Use css column attribute as it is not supported in IE :(
- Use javascript (Columnizer) to split my divs into two sets. 
  This is because I am turning these tiles into draggables and the javascript code 
  considerably hinders the usability of my application.
- I can't use special selectors for left and right boxes as the list of boxes is dynamic (knockout generated)

Is this even achievable?

Comment: How about absolute positioning?

Comment: Will you always have 2 columns? Is it possible from the server side to split the result in half - marking the left & right?

Comment: @aland Yes, the plan is to have two columns only. I would rather split that in the client side instead I think :)

Comment: @php_nub_qq Absolute positioning won't fit here. I can't position 100s of boxes this way :)

Comment: @GETah well if facebook can, for instance, then I believe you can too `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two floating to the left `<divs>`s as a columns (no "column" property), and put boxes in them in desired order.

```
<div class="MylistPart">
 <div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:75px;"><span>Box 1</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:65px;"><span>Box 2</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="MylistPart">
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:45px;"><span>Box 3</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:85px;"><span>Box 4</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:25px;"><span>Box 5</span></div>
 </div>
</div>

.MyList
{
    overflow:auto;
    background:lightgray;
    width:240px;
}
.ListItem {
    color: #000;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width:100px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.MylistPart{
    float:left;
    width:110;
    background:lightgreen;
}
```

**EDIT**
I edited your solution and added the floating and it is now working fine ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa2Cv/)
Although special selectors are used for the left and right side columns, these can easily be used with dynamic content where the initial array of boxes has to be split into two parts and then let knockout loop through these two parts to display them.

Answer (score 2):

```
.leftBoxes
{
  display: inline; 
  float: left; 
  width: 49%; 
}
.rightBoxes
{
  display: inline;
  float: right; 
  width: 49%;
}
#box1
{
  height: 100px;
}
#box2
{
  height: 20px;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I unfortunately can't go this way (please see my edited constraints)

Comment: Make sure the widths of each are not interfering with each other.

Comment: What do you mean by this? The parent container is large enough to contain both elements inlined. The problem is not the width but the height :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a `<table>`?

```
<div class="MyList">
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:75px;"><span>Box 1</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:65px;"><span>Box 2</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:45px;"><span>Box 3</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:85px;"><span>Box 4</span></div>
   <div class="ListItem" style="height:25px;"><span>Box 5</span></div>
</div>
```

Would change to

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="ListItem" style="height:75px;"><span>Box 1</span></div>
                    <div class="ListItem" style="height:45px;"><span>Box 3</span></div>
                    <div class="ListItem" style="height:25px;"><span>Box 5</span></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="ListItem" style="height:65px;"><span>Box 2</span></div>
                    <div class="ListItem" style="height:85px;"><span>Box 4</span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

*I love tables :P

Here's the [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzdsz/1/) Re-edit.

Comment: Fine for a fixed number of items with known dimensions. I get this not the case as the question mentions specifically 'dynamic' content